# How can I get data from $.getjson

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I code jquery like this

```
var machineId = [];
$.getJSON('ajax/getmachines.php', { plant: vPlant, floor: vBuilding + vFloor }, function(dataList) {
    $.each(dataList, function(recordno, machine) {
        machineId.push(machine['id']);
        alert(machine['id']);
    });
}); 

alert(machineId[0]);
```

The first alert in the `$.each` shows the right data every record but why the last alert show me undefined? How can I use array `machineId`? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post plain text response from server?

Comment: I suggest you use a proper debugging tool like Firebug. Plain `alert()` is pretty unsuitable to display complex data.

Answer (score 2):

The request is asynchronous so the last alert is executed before the array is filled. Try to place the "alert(machineId[0])" after the $.each operation.

Answer (score 0):

The `getJSON` method is asynchronous - when the run time engine reach the last alert, it didn't finish to execute yet.

You can't use the array before the callback has finished.

Just do whatever you need to do from within the callback, for example:

```
$.each(dataList, function(recordno, machine) {
    machineId.push(machine['id']);
    alert(machine['id']);
});
alert(machineId.join(", "));
```

This will show all the ID's separated with comma.

Comment: Thank you, dear shadow wizard. But the point is I would like to get the value to use at the other function like this
function getmachineId(machineId) {
      var machineId = [];
      $.getJSON('ajax/getmachines.php', { plant: vPlant, floor: vBuilding + vFloor },        function(dataList) {
          $.each(dataList, function(recordno, machine) {
            machineId.push(machine['id']);
          });
     }); 
  }
  var machineId = [];
  for (i=0, i<machineId, i++) {
     alert(machineId[i]);
  }
But the show me undefined value. How can I solve this problems.
Thanks again
Narongdetch

Comment: You can't, you'll have to rethink the logic involved.